# Limit function call

Tags: c++, function

What is the best way to limit a function call in c++?

I have async requests from webserver to a function. The problem is the program will crash if the request rate is so high (the function will be called multiple times before others finish). I want to limit it to certain number, by storing the request in queue first and then the queue will manage the call to the function.

I already create 2 classes, RQServer and RQClient.

**rqueue.h**

```
class RQServer {
    public:
        RQServer();
        std::queue<Request> *getQueue();
    private:
        std::queue<Request> _requests;
};

class RQClient {
    public:
        RQClient();
        bool connect(RQServer server);
        bool push(Request req);
    private:
        std::queue<Requst> *_requests;
};
```

**rqueue.cpp**

```
#include "rqueue.h"

RQServer::RQServer(){}

std::queue<Request> *RQServer::getQueue(){
    return &_requests;
}

RQClient::RQClient(){}

RQClient::connect(RQServer server){
    _requests = server.getQueue();
}

RQClient::push(Request req){
    _requests -> push(req);
}
```

One obvious way is to create a method `RQServer::run()` that create threads according to the allowed async calls (say I set `limit` variable) to the function , and each thread will always check the queue. The problem is when the `limit` is hundreds.

Comment: Show some [MCVE] in your question. What exactly do you want to limit: the number of threads (you could have some thread pool), the call stack depth? So **edit your question** to improve it a lot.

Comment: Do you correctly protect your data for concurrency accesses with mutexes or similar ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I will implement mutex if I am going to use threads. The problem is I don't know if using threads is the best way to go, since the program can create hundreds of threads If I use threads.

Answer (score 0):

While a MCVe is lacking, say you start like this.

1. You have a bounded set of worker threads.
2. Each thread, once done with the current request, dequeues a new request and starts working on it.
3. There's a queue at the front to smooth out requests. It should be bounded and drop requests after a limit is reached. This means your backend is 100% occupied and unable to service incoming requests.
4. Your front end, user visible, server should receive a request and either queue it or drop if the limit is reached.

By no means shall you ever create a new thread to service a new request. The whole point of having a queue is to decouple your worker threads from the receiver side and absorb any transients.